# Top level exception is breaking my page (PHP)

Tags: php

I'm studying PHP right now and I'm using [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp),  but when I use the code below my page gets broken (stops from where the code is):

```
<?php
function myException($exception) {
  echo "<b>Exception:</b> " . $exception->getMessage();
}

set_exception_handler('myException');

throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception occurred');
?>
```

This code is for creating an exception when no catch block was found.

I tried the others examples in the page and everything works fine. I thought it may be happening because there is no try block, but I'm confused and I don't know how to use it in this situation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this all your code?

Comment: This code is working fine for me. can you provide what is the error message you are getting. use error_reporting(E_ALL); in the first line for displaying error messages

Comment: DevMan only the part that gives me the error. | Ravinder Reddy Nothing happens. :/

Comment: why don't you use try catch for that?

Comment: try this: `try{throw new \Exception('Uncaught Exception occurred');}catch(\Exception $e ){ echo '<b>Exception:</b>'.$e->getMessage();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the output you are getting is correct.

As stated in W3Schools documentation `set_exception_handler()` only sets a user-defined function to handle all uncaught exceptions (as in the example you quoted above). So the output should be something like this:

```
Exception: Uncaught Exception occurred
```

Please notice the form of exception is what you have defined in your function (myException); which means first it prints the word `Exception:` and then it prints the reason (message) of exception, in this case `Uncaught Exception occurred`.

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments the error handler causes the script to stop being executed. To avoid this situation is better always to handle exceptions using [`try catch blocks`](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-exceptions--net-22274).

*P.S: I'd suggest you to use better resources other than W3Schools (like the PHP documentations itself) if you are starting to learn PHP.*

Comment: I get this error, but my page should be blank after this? :/ I get the basic, but I think it's hard to find more advanced classes in other sources for free.

Comment: @B.Pereira Yes, your code stops executing after calling exception handler. For more examples you could have a look at examples in this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

Comment: @B.Pereira To avoid this situation you should better always catch the exceptions in your script using Try-Catch. Please have a look at this page for more examples: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Ok. I'll use Try-Catch blocks when I need this in the future. I was confused because of W3Schools, but I get lost in the manual of php.net. ;3; Anyway, thank you, @Hatef!

Answer (score 2):

set_exception_handler documentation from php.net:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

> Execution will stop after the exception_handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

try this. Hope it helps. If not please let me know.

```
 function myException($exception) {  
     try {
            throw new Exception("Some error message");
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    set_exception_handler('myException');
    throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception occurred');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my page is still blank after the code :(